# Flink set timer on non keyed stream

Tags: apache-flink

Can Flink set timer on the non-keyed stream?

`ProcessAllWindowFunction`is a good option. But it cannot scale up the parallelism. It has to be 1.

I am looking for such non-keyed process function that can set a timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink's timers are only available within keyed process functions.

The standard answer to this question is to go ahead and key the stream, adding a field holding a random number to use as the key (if there isn't already a suitable way to implement a key selector).

If you can't live with the expense of a network shuffle, for event-time timers  you could implement a custom operator that implements your logic in its `processWatermark` method.

And if you are looking for processing-time timers, you could roll your own.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious that why Flink somehow deprecates the timer feature in ProcessFunction? Flink used to support that in the older version.

Comment: That was before the introduction of KeyedProcessFunction. Changes were made to the APIs to ensure that state and timers could be rescaled.

Answer (score 0):

you could `keyBy(_ => None)` or keyBy() a constant and still use timers

Comment: Will this result in all events going to only one instance and the workload bcomes imbalanced?

Comment: That's right, not ideal for larger workloads